# Scope of non-static variables in static objects

Tags: java, static, abstract

I am not able to understand a piece of code i have encountered.

Following is a similar piece of code:

```
class GrandParent  
{  
        private Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();  

        protected void insertString(String key, String value)  
        {  
                map.put(key, value);  
        }  
}  

abstract class AbstractParent extends GrandParent  
{  
        private static AbstractParent parent1;  

        public static AbstractParent getParent1Instance()  
        {  
                if(parent1 == null)  
                {  
                        parent1 = new ImplementingChild();  
                }  

                return parent1;  
        }  

        public void populateStringMapInitial()  
        {  
                for(int count = 0; count < 10; count++)  
                {  
                        insertString("" + count, "parent count value = "+count);  
                }  
        }  

        public void populateStringMapNext()  
        {  
                for(int count = 10; count < 20; count++)  
                {  
                        insertString("" + count, "parent count value = "+count);  
                }  
        }  
}  

class ImplementingChild extends AbstractParent  
{  
        public void populateStringMapInitial()  
        {  
                for(int count = 0; count < 10; count++)  
                {  
                        insertString("" + count, "child count value = "+count);  
                }  
        }  

        public void populateStringMapNext()  
        {  
                for(int count = 10; count < 20; count++)  
                {  
                        insertString("" + count, "child count value = "+count);  
                }  
        }  
}
```

What is the scope of the 'map' variable if i create a static instance of the AbstractParent via the child ?
Map is private to GrandParent (i.e. at object level) and the object of AbstractParent is static (i.e. at class level). Could there
be a possibility that 'map' variable could be eligible for garbage collection even when AbstractParent(Child) instance exists ?

Secondly, what could be the reason behind this kind of design ?

I tested the aforementioned code to have a non-static reference to the static instance of AbstractParent as in the following example:

```
class AbstractAndStaticTest {  

    public static void main(String[] args)  
    {  
        AbstractParent parent1 = AbstractParent.getParent1Instance();  
        parent1.populateStringMapInitial();  
        parent1 = null;  

        AbstractParent parent2 = AbstractParent.getParent1Instance();  
        parent2.populateStringMapNext();  

        System.out.println();  
    }  
}
```

and found that the map contains all the 20 elements. Can anyone explain the reason behind this ? I guess i am missing something very basic over here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess i am missing something very basic over here.

Very basic thing. Static variable, or, other said, class-level variable is shared among all instances of the class. So you have only one instance of class-level variable:

```
private static AbstractParent parent1;
```

and every request to `AbstractParent.getParent1Instance()` returns that one and always the same instance.

Your method-level declaration in main:

```
AbstractParent parent1
```

doesn't change anything because it's in completely method local and in completely different class, AbstractAndStaticTest, so parent1 = null only makes AbstractParent instance eligible for Garbage Collection, but not Class object and not Class level instances, as they get never eligible for GC.

Comment: My question is what is the scope of the 'map' variable. As it can be seen that 'Map' is private to GrandParent and we are creating an object of Child, hence, map shouldn't be in the scope of Child.

Comment: And it isn't, what make you thinking the other way? The pattern above is singleton. `static getParent1Instance()` will only once create new instance, subsequent requests will return same object. Hence, you end up having 20 elements.

Answer (score 0):

Since your code goes:

```
    AbstractParent parent2 = AbstractParent.getParent1Instance();  
    parent2.populateStringMapNext();
```

`parent2` should have all the 20 items as your function goes.

At the same time, since `parent1` is defined as follows:

```
AbstractParent parent1 = AbstractParent.getParent1Instance();  
parent1.populateStringMapInitial();
```

`parent1` would have the 10 items as per the Initial setting you defined.

And when you do:

```
parent1 = null;
```

there's nothing there.

What's your exact query here?